# Parsing ASCII files to a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

For a project, I need to get some word definitions in a database. All the definitions can be found on multiple DB files, but the DB files that I got are for a C language program and are in the form of ASCII (I believe). I need to somehow phrase thorough the files, line by line add the data into a MySQL database.

I would prefer using PHP and/or MySQL.

I tried writing a PHP script to go through and do it, but it timed-out and is intensive on my system and in most cases don't complete.

I heard about [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) from MySQL but have no clue how to use it with this.

The file names change for each file and do not have a specific extension, however, all of them can be read from a text file, and I am sure they are all the same in terms of content.

I uploaded the contents of one file [here](http://pastebin.com/GdXvvHZq).

You can see that some lines are useless, but the lines starting with `{` are good and the pattern is essentially the first word is the dictionary term, and the content within `()` are the definitions. The parts within the `""` are sample sentences.

All I need to extract are the terms, definitions and sentences.

The definitions are provided by Princeton University and the license is open source (and I will be crediting them).

Comment: Try searching for "parsing text to MySQL" on Google to start with. I've seen some results that might be of interest.

Comment: Also, sharing the PHP script you wrote might be of use to anyone who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to reinvent the wheel I would go with something like [wordnet2sql](http://www.semantilog.org/wn2sql.html). It will output an SQL script that you can use to create your MySQL tables.

You can find the database specifications on [princeton's website](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html).

LOAD DATA is useful for csv files but not so much for special database formats.

Comment: I am not familiar with wordnet2sql. Do you mind expanding on it?

Comment: Somehow the link got broken off in my answer. http://www.semantilog.org/wn2sql.html or [Let me google that for you](http://bit.ly/JcqlqV)